# How to stream to AWS S3 using pipeline function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream

I want to stream upload to AWS S3 using the `pipeline` function from Node.js's native `stream` module, but I'm not sure how to do this.

[AWS's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-lib-storage/) shows how to upload using their `Upload` function, but I'm not sure how to convert this into a WritableStream that can be passed into Node.js's [pipeline](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streampipelinesource-transforms-destination-callback) function.